# Вызов фрагмента с RecycleView из другого фрагмента

Tags: android, android-fragment, recycleview

Написал код, который из одного фрагмента (А) через кнопку вызывает другой фрагмент (Б). Все работало хорошо, пока не реализовал в фрагменте Б RecycleView. Теперь при нажатии на кнопку во фрагменте А ничего не происходит. То есть на экране остается отображение Фрагмента А. При этом, повторно на кнопку нажать не дает - словно она уже не доступна. 
Не совсем понимаю, чего я не так сделал.
Вот код активити

```
public class MainMenuActivity extends FragmentActivity {


android.app.FragmentTransaction ft = 
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_menu_activity);

    ShowMenuFragment();

}

public void ShowListOfGoodsFragment() {
    GoodsFragment listOfGoodsFragment = new GoodsFragment();

    ft.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer1, listOfGoodsFragment);
    ft.addToBackStack("example");
    ft.setTransition(android.app.FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
    ft.commit();
}

public void ShowMenuFragment() {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer1);
    if (fragment == null) {
        fragment = new MenuFragment();
        fm.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragmentContainer1, fragment)
                .commit();
    }
}}
```

код для Фрагмента А (MenuFragment)

```
public class MenuFragment extends Fragment {
Button PushListOfGoods;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstance);
}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstance) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu, container, false);

    PushListOfGoods = v.findViewById(R.id.PushListOfGoods);
    PushListOfGoods.setOnClickListener(Cliker);

    return v;
}

View.OnClickListener Cliker = new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        MainMenuActivity currentActivity = (MainMenuActivity)getActivity();
        currentActivity.ShowListOfGoodsFragment();
    }
};}
```

Код фрагмента Б

```
public class GoodsFragment extends Fragment {

public RecyclerView mShopRecyclerView;
private ShopAdapter mShopAdapter;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstance);
}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstance) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_of_goods_fragment, container, false);
    mShopRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) v
            .findViewById(R.id.mlist_of_goods_fragment);
    mShopRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager
            (getActivity()));
    updateUI();

    return v;
}

private void updateUI() {
    ArrayOfGoods arrayOfGoods = ArrayOfGoods.get(getActivity());
    List<Goods> goods = arrayOfGoods.getShopGoods();
    mShopAdapter = new ShopAdapter(goods);
    mShopRecyclerView.setAdapter(mShopAdapter);
}

private class ShopHolder extends ViewHolder {

    private TextView mTitleTextView;
    private TextView priceTextView;
    private Goods mGoods;

    public ShopHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mTitleTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.row_item_title_text);
        priceTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.row_item_price_text);
    }

    public void findGoods(Goods goods){
        mGoods = goods;
        mTitleTextView.setText(mGoods.getTitleGoods());
        priceTextView.setText(mGoods.getPrice());
    }

}

private class ShopAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ShopHolder> {

    private List<Goods> mShopGoods;

    public ShopAdapter(List<Goods> ShopGoods) {
        mShopGoods = ShopGoods;
    }


    @Override
    public ShopHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
        View view = layoutInflater
                .inflate(R.layout.row_item, parent, false);
        return new ShopHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ShopHolder holder, int position) {
        Goods goods = mShopGoods.get(position);
        holder.findGoods(goods);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mShopGoods.size();
    }
}}
```

Разметка фрагмента Б

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/mlist_of_goods_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

В методе `updateUI` перед передачей адаптера реализуйте `LinearLayoutManager` для `RecyclerView`.

```
mShopRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
```

Comment: Спасибо, вставил, только не помогло. И вместо setLinearLayoutManager дает вставить только setLayoutManager.

Comment: Пардон, исправил сообщение. Вы вызываете его в перед методом `updateUI();`, Перед этим методом удалите `mShopRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager
            (getActivity()));` и вставьте его в сам метод `updateUI` перед `mShopRecyclerView.setAdapter(mShopAdapter);`

Comment: Ок, в методе updateUI вставил mShopRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager (getActivity())).  А вызывать перед updateUI() - это прописать перед ним setLayoutManager()?

Comment: Он у вас там прописан уже, перед вызывом `updateUI`, удалите оттуда, только в самом методе пусть будет

Comment: Делаю так - не помогает...

Comment: Может, проблема в наполнении списка данными из базы. Я db-код здесь не приводил пока...